# i want to fetch comma separated record in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, select, in-operator, find-in-set

In my database table I have 6 Columns id(auto),title,news,image,type
I write this query.

```
select id,title,image 
from add_news 
where FIND_IN_SET('Travel','Music',type) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I am getting this error

```
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET'
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  And even the most cursory Google search brings you to the documentation for that function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: 1. See normalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that `type` is a comma-delimited list.  This is a very poor data format, and you should have a separate table with one row per type and article.

But, given the format, the correct syntax is:

```
select id, title, image
from add_news
where find_in_set('Travel', type) > 0 or
      find_in_set('Music', type) > 0
order by id desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **IN** operator instead of **FIND_IN_SET()**

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id, A.title, A.image 
FROM add_news A
WHERE A.type IN ('Travel', 'Music')
ORDER BY A.id DESC
```